# How to prevent node.js process from restarting on Azure topology change

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a node.js service running in Azure as worker role. By default the process is restarted every time there is a topology change, e.g. instance count is increased via Azure portal. How can I prevent this restart?

MSDN documentation pointed to handling Azure's "Changing" event.  Azure Node SDK's support for cancelling was added [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/commit/c504daaa02c7bef75132c3d4dadae3367b8a93ea#diff-093e1a84cb8ded6f35b54c229e5d6674) and [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/commit/42fd6148324b987672b64d0aa1c4d698489630fe#diff-093e1a84cb8ded6f35b54c229e5d6674).

The code to use the API would be something like

```
azure.RoleEnvironment.on(ServiceRuntimeConstants.CHANGING, function (changes) {
   changes.cancel();
});
```

From logs I know the handler is called, but restarts still took place afterwards.  Am I using the API incorrectly or is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Role Changing event in .NET when you cancel the event you are actually asking the system to restart.  The docs for the [Role Changing event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) say this:

> By using the Cancel property, you can ensure that the instance
>   proceeds through an orderly shutdown sequence and is taken offline
>   before the configuration change is applied. During the shutdown
>   process, Windows Azure raises the Stopping event, and then runs any
>   code in the OnStop method.

The idea of the Role Changing event is that if you can modify the configuration at runtime without requiring a restart you do so.  By cancelling the changing event you are in essence saying, "I can't change this at runtime, so restart gracefully and pick up the new changes then."

I've not tried this with Node, but try not cancelling it.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I had started with the opposite of not cancelling the event.  That didn't work, so I started experimenting with the opposite.